# Выбор коллекции при парсинге XML?

Tags: java, android, xml, sax

Есть такой xml-файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<list>
<file name="a" size="559393"/>
<file name="b" size="1766945"/>
</list>
```

С помощью SAX-парсера мне нужно достать значения атрибутов (в моем случае значения name и size у всех тегов **file**) и записать в коллекцию для дальнейшей работы программы.

Как мне лучше это реализовать? Для каждого тега file создавать объект с полями name и size и добавлять всё это в ArrayList Object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты сам ответил на свой вопрос

```
public class File{

   public File(String name, long size){
      this.name = name;
      this.size = size;
   }

   private String name;
   private long  size;

   //GETteri i SETteri
}
```

И уже где парсиш ХМL

```
ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList();
//logic to parse xml
files.add(new File(name,size);
```

Ты пишешь на ООП языке так что используй все его фичи.